# Go to symbol within same file

Tags: android-studio

Is there a shortcut that allows me to go to a symbol (method, object, etc) within the same file?  Currently I'm using CMD + ALT + O to find symbols, but it seems to default to super class implementations.  For example, I'm within SubClass which overrides SomeMethod from SuperClass.  When I use CMD + ALT + O to find the symbol "SomeMethod" Android Studio only returns the implementation of that method in the super class "SuperClass".  I believe there has to be a way to do this as I was able to do it when I switched to Eclipse shortcuts (I don't want to use Eclipse shortcuts).

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cmd+F12 shows the "quick outline" pop-up. Pressing it repeatedly toggles inherited members.